# Fully show all files in a directory --- but with some spacing between them

Tags: bash, wildcards, cat

In CentOS with Bash 3.2.52 I desire to fully-show all files in say current dir:

```
cat *
```

All files' outputs are displaying but they are totally **juxtaposed** one to another...

I lack some cosmetic spacing right there, that would ease understanding which file starts where.

Instead:

```
file-output_1
file-output_2
```

I'd like say:

```
file_output_1

file_output_2
```

How could I improve the cat and shell glob command, so that each file-output (maybe besides the last) will have some spacing under it, say 1 or 2 empty lines)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind getting a filename header as well as the spacing, then least with the GNU Coreutils implementations of `head`/`tail` you could do

```
tail -n +1 *
```

or

```
head -n -0 *
```

Comment: Good tricks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `more` command instead of `cat`. For example:

```
$ touch file{01..05}
$ for i in {01..05};do echo string$i > file$i;done

$ ll
total 40
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 9 Sep  6 20:38 file01
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 9 Sep  6 20:38 file02
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 9 Sep  6 20:38 file03
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 9 Sep  6 20:38 file04
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 9 Sep  6 20:38 file05
```

Now to use `more`:

```
$ more file*
::::::::::::::
file01
::::::::::::::
string1
::::::::::::::
file02
::::::::::::::
string2
::::::::::::::
file03
::::::::::::::
string3
::::::::::::::
file04
::::::::::::::
string4
::::::::::::::
file05
::::::::::::::
string5
```